# INSERT ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET (an UPSERT) statement with a unique constraint is generating constraint violations when run concurrently

Tags: postgresql

I am attempting to run an Postgres `UPSERT` in fairly concurrent code. I have been seeing a `duplicate key value violates unique constraint` error when my service is under load.

By way of a reduced example, I have the following table, which has an `id` primary key and an `id_secondary` unique key (meant to function as a second ID)

```sql
CREATE TABLE "test_table" (
    "id" text NOT NULL,
    "id_secondary" text NOT NULL,
    "value" bool NOT NULL DEFAULT 'FALSE',
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "test_table_uc" ON "public"."test_table" USING BTREE ("id_secondary");
```

I am running the following two statements simultaneously:

```sql
INSERT INTO "test_table" ("id", "id_secondary", "value") VALUES('1', '1', 'false') 
ON CONFLICT ("id")
  DO UPDATE
  SET "value" = "excluded"."value";

INSERT INTO "test_table" ("id", "id_secondary", "value") VALUES('1', '1', 'true') 
ON CONFLICT ("id")
  DO UPDATE
  SET "value" = "excluded"."value";
```

and it is my expectation that whichever statement executes last will be the one to set the value of `"value"`.

Occasionally I am receiving the error `duplicate key value violates unique constraint "test_table_uc"` from one of these statements. My full test setup in Go (using testify) is:

```go
suite.Run("Concurrency", func() {
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "host=localhost port=35432 dbname=test sslmode=disable user=postgres")
    db.SetMaxOpenConns(10)
    suite.Require().NoError(err)

    for ii := 0; ii < 100; ii++ {
        wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
        wg.Add(2)

        go func() {
            _, err := db.Exec(`
                    INSERT INTO "test_table" ("id", "id_secondary", "value") VALUES($1, $2, 'false') 
                    ON CONFLICT ("id")
                        DO UPDATE
                            SET
                                "value" = "excluded"."value"
                `, ii, ii)
            suite.Require().NoError(err)
            wg.Done()
        }()

        go func() {
            _, err := db.Exec(`
                    INSERT INTO "test_table" ("id", "id_secondary", "value") VALUES($1, $2, 'true') 
                    ON CONFLICT ("id") 
                        DO UPDATE
                            SET
                                "value" = "excluded"."value"
                `, ii, ii)
            suite.Require().NoError(err)
            wg.Done()
        }()
        wg.Wait()
    }
})
```

Where I am allowing concurrent SQL connections using `db.SetMaxOpenConns(10)` and the `go func()` syntax is running both SQL statements in different goroutines (threads). Only two of the statements are run at a time, and the value of `"id"` and `"id_secondary"` are always set to the loop iteration. I wait for both statements to return before iterating.

It generally fails with the `duplicate key value violates unique constraint` error within a few loops.

I have not modified my isolation settings and I am running in `SHOW default_transaction_isolation = read committed`, on PostgreSQL 9.6.24

### My Question

At no point is the statement generating a row that does not satisfy the unique constraints of the table. Seemingly, both statements are attempting to insert data at the same time. The Postgres documentation states that:

> ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE guarantees an atomic INSERT or UPDATE outcome; provided there is no independent error, one of those two outcomes is guaranteed, even under high concurrency. This is also known as UPSERT — “UPDATE or INSERT”.
> which I interpreting to mean that the INSERT or UPDATE happens atomically, they should never attempt to write in data with the same primary key.

For the `test_table_uc` constraint to be violated, then in my example, the primary key uniqueness constraint must also be breaking. This is very surprising to me.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

After reading through the Postgres source code I believe I have found a satisfying answer to this.

In the `ON CONFLICT` statements given, only `id` is mentioned as a column. This will cause Postgres to use `test_table_pkey` as an arbiter index.

Normally, when evaluating an `ON CONFLICT` Postgres will speculatively insert the new row, and check only the arbiter indexes for conflicts (against currently committed rows) using `ExecCheckIndexConstraints`. If there is a conflict on `test_table_pkey` and `test_table_uc` it will only be checking for the arbiter index `test_table_pkey`, which will have a conflict and cause Postgres to revert to the `ON CONFLICT` clause.

If two of these `INSERT` expressions are occurring at the same time, neither will see each other (as they are both speculative and both pass `ExecCheckIndexConstraints`). This will cause Postgres to attempt to commit both speculative rows. The first row will commit properly. The second row will cause two constraint violations during `ExecInsertIndexTuples`. The function `ExecInsertIndexTuples` will suppress errors on any *arbiter indexes only*, meaning that the constraint violation on `test_table_pkey` will get caught (and cause Postgres to retry the insert from the top), but the `test_table_uc` violation will become an uncaught error which causes the statement to error.

Essentially, this means if your upsert is potentially causing conflicts on constraints that are not named in the `ON CONFLICT` clause, these statements will fail, **but only during concurrent inserts**.